# i am trying to run the command "pacman -Syu" on "msys2" and it doesn't work

Tags: ssl, msys2, msys, pacman-package-manager

I just installed the window64 version of msys2 and I try to update the package database and base packages running the "pacman -Syu" command.
I get this error :

```
$ pacman -Syu
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 mingw32.db failed to download
 mingw64.db failed to download
 ucrt64.db failed to download
 clang32.db failed to download
 clang64.db failed to download
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw32.db' from mirror.msys2.org : SSL connection timeout
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw64.db' from mirror.msys2.org : SSL connection timeout
error: failed retrieving file 'ucrt64.db' from mirror.msys2.org : SSL connection timeout
warning: too many errors from mirror.msys2.org, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed retrieving file 'clang32.db' from mirror.msys2.org : SSL connection timeout
error: failed retrieving file 'clang64.db' from mirror.msys2.org : SSL connection timeout
error: failed retrieving file 'mingw32.db' from repo.msys2.org : SSL connection timeout
```

if anyone has an idea i would appreciate it.

Comment: Something wrong with the internet connection? Or ISP blocking the URL?

Comment: nothing wrong with the internet connection. but yes i think its because of the security of the internet from the enterprise i am working in.

Comment: What's your Msys2 installation directory?

Comment: If your organisation is blocking the URLs, you could try to set a proxy server to bypass it (e.g. `export http_proxy=http://proxy.local:8080/`).

Answer (score 0):

It could be a DNS resolver issue. What is in your /etc/resolv.conf?

In IPV4, this is known to work well.

go to /etc/ directory and edit resolv.conf file

set these DNS servers and try them:

nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8